# access inner attributes of builtins

Tags: python, attributes, abstraction, built-in

I have a simple question. As everything is an object in python, can I access the inner attributes of a builtin object.

e.g. `a='some String'`
I want to access in the inner attributes of the string object `a`.

Here is what I'have tried:-

```
 for x in dir(a):
  if not callable(eval('a.' + x)):
   print x
```

But, I get output as:

`__doc__`

But, I want to access other attributes from this object, which the object will be using for itself.

Is there a way through which I can access the abstract attributes of this object ?

Just to elaborate:

```
class Some(object):
 def __init__(self, initialiser):
  self.initialiser = initialiser

s = Some('Any object can be put here, I am using a string')

print s.initialiser ## This is how I'm accessing the attribute of the class Some. Similarly, can I ##access the attributes of the string object `a` defined above?
```

`print s` # gives me: `<__main__.Some object at 0x02371AF0>`

So, why does `print a` not give me such an output. Because, some method is called when I print `a` and which accesses the memory where the actual string sequence is stored and prints it. But, this does not happen when I print `s`

Comment: What "inner variables" or "abstract variables" do you want to access? And what do you mean by those terms?

Comment: What do you mean by "inner variables"?

Comment: What makes you think that there is such a thing?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of an attribute you can't access on an object that you want to be able to?  Also, use `getattr(a, x)`, not `eval()`.

Comment: this looks like bad design ... maybe rethink what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @delnan: I am thinking that just like I can access the attributes of any custom object, can I access the attributes of a builtin object

Comment: Yes.  Just use dot accessors like any other object.

Comment: @sr2222: How do I know which attribute to use dot accessor with? I mean I should first know what attributes are present, then, only I can access them

Comment: @GodMan I mean, what makes you think there are attributes on these objects? Sure, if there were some, you could access them. But what attributes would you expect on, say, an integer? BTW `dir()`'s result can be overriden by objects, but it is generally accurate.

Comment: That's why objects have documentation that describes their interfaces.  If you really can't be sure what attributes there are on the object, introspection (`dir()` for example) can tell you.

Comment: @GodMan: many builtin objects have no attributes.  This is because they are implemented in C as C structs, and their data is not exposed as Python attributes.

Comment: You can access anything that is there.  The question is, what do you think is there to access?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Here's some proof to back up your assertion: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2370e331241b/Objects/stringobject.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very little you cannot access in Python, as there are few, if any, private attributes to the Python build-in types.

You really want to go read up on the [python datamodel](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), and study the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) (including it's [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/inspect.py)).

That'll tell you all you need to know about what you can and cannot access in python.

Comment: For the OP's specific question, you could also include a link to the source for python's built in objects (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects), or if OP is particularly concerned about the built in string object, http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects .

Comment: @Wilduck: the data model explains most; to start mixing in the C implementations (which requires an understanding of the C API) is a little too much to ask at this stage, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

Unless overridden, `dir()` will provide you with a list of all of the non-mangled attributes on an object (and *if* overridden it's usually for a good reason). The reason you get `__doc__` as your output is it's the only non-callable attribute on the string type, the rest are methods. You can access it directly via normal attribute look-up:

```
>>> s = 'string'
>>> print s.__doc__
str(object) -> string

Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
```

What other attributes were you expecting the `str` type to have?

As for why printing a string gives you the string while printing a class gives you a more abstract representation: `print` calls the `__str__` method on an object, which allows for a human friendly display to be provided. For strings, this is quite obviously the string itself. For classes, a more generic default is used.

Comment: As you said, __str__ allows for a human friendly display to be provided. I have a question on that:

Human friendly display of what?? the string object must be holding a variable which the __str__ accesses to provide a human friendly display. is it ?

Comment: `str` is implemented in C: however it stores the string internally, that isn't directly exposed to the interpreter. You might find this article on [Python string object implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/) interesting. The bigger question here is: what are you trying to achieve from this?

Comment: I am trying to increase my knowledge on Python internals by asking this question.

Comment: "the string object must be holding a variable which the str accesses to provide a human friendly display". Yes; the string object *is* that variable.

Answer (score -1):

When you do print obj, python calls the `__str__` method on the object. For a string, the result is obvious, but for your custom classes, the default `__str__` method calls `__repr__`, which returns some useful information. I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer your *actual* question, just the question you actually asked.